# How do I disable #warning message in GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

There is a pre-processor directive in GCC called #warning, which simply issues a warning at compile time with the string that is attached. The GCC [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says that this can be disabled with the `-Wno-cpp` flag. However, this flag does not seem to function. I am using 
GCC 4.4.3.

A simple test case is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#warning "Hello"

int main() {
}
```

which results in this:

```
$ g++ warn.cc 
warn.cc:2:2: warning: #warning "Hello"
$ g++ warn.cc -Wno-cpp
warn.cc:2:2: warning: #warning "Hello"
```

Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: It works (i.e. suppresses the warning) here with g++ 4.6.1. Maybe a bug?

Comment: On GCC 4.6.1, the `-Wno-cpp` flag works as expected for me (just as a data point).

Comment: The docs you reference are about gcc version 4.8.0.  It likely does not work on gcc 4.4.3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Wno-cpp` apparently wasn't added until GCC 4.6.x - it's not in the docs up through those for version 4.5.3: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/index.html#toc_Invoking-GCC